# "lldb" crash with XCODE & ARKIT : 0 __ UpdateAudioTransform

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have written a game using ARKIT that pops up random nodes (with drones) in the 3d space around the player, using ARKIT, and I get an incomprehensible crash, as only thing in the console is "lldb" , and the rest of the crash details are on the screenshot attached (I am still a newbie in Swift so not able to debug it).

**The crash happens when there's a lot of nodes on the screen (maybe 20-30) and the FPS drops - ie happens "mid - game" and the FPS drops a lot.**

Can someone point me to the right direction for this crash?

The part of the code that is in my opinion relevant is the function that spawns the random 3d nodes (they also have SCNActions attached that play sounds when they're tapped - perhaps this could be relevant as the left hand side debugger opens with that line highlighted when the crash occurs, as per the photo attached). In case it is also relevant, the program uses some SCNParticleSystem calls as well. Attaching relevant code, and also the snapshot of the crash screen:

```
var droneSound : SCNAudioSource()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
droneSound = SCNAudioSource(named: "Sounds/drone1.wav")!
playDroneSound = SCNAction.playAudio(self.droneSound, waitForCompletion: true)
   }

func startGame() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.spawnTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(self.randomFloat(min: 2.5, max: 5)), target: self, selector: #selector(self.spawnDronesInterim), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

}
@objc func spawnDronesInterim() {
    for _ in 0...5 {
        spawnDrone()
    }
}

@objc func spawnDrone() {

        let newDroneScene = SCNScene(named: "Ar.scnassets/DroneScene.scn")!
        var newDroneNode = newDroneScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Drone", recursively: false)!

        newDroneNode.name = "Drone\(self.droneCounter)"
        newDroneNode = newDroneScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Drone\(self.droneCounter)", recursively: false)!

        newDroneNode.position.x = newDroneNode.presentation.position.x + self.randomFloat(min: -10, max: 10)
        newDroneNode.position.y = newDroneNode.presentation.position.y + self.randomFloat(min: -1, max: 5)
        newDroneNode.position.z = newDroneNode.presentation.position.z + self.randomFloat(min: -10, max: 10)

        let move1 = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3((self.randomFloat(min: -7, max: 7)), (self.randomFloat(min: 1, max: 5)), (self.randomFloat(min: -7, max: 7))), duration: 15)

        let disappearMove = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3((self.randomFloat(min: -10, max: 10)), (self.randomFloat(min: 1, max: 5)), (self.randomFloat(min: -10, max: 10))), duration: 3)

        let rotateAction = SCNAction.run { (SCNNode) in
            let rotate = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(360.degreesToRadians), z: 0, duration: 2)
            newDroneNode.runAction(rotate)
        }

        let removeIt = SCNAction.removeFromParentNode()

        let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([waitFive,move1,rotateAction,waitFive,disappearMove,waitTwo,removeIt])

        newDroneNode.runAction(sequence)

        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newDroneNode)

        if self.droneCounter >= 5 {
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Drone\(self.droneCounter)", recursively: true)!.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(self.playDroneSound))
        }
        self.droneCounter += 1


}
```

when user taps on one of the 3d nodes, this gets called:

```
func handleExplosion (node : SCNNode) {

    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: node.name!, recursively: true)!.runAction(self.playExplosionSound)


    node.opacity = 0

    print (self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.position)

    let confetti = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Ar.scnassets/confetti.scnp", inDirectory: nil)
    confetti?.loops = false
    confetti?.particleLifeSpan = 1.5
    confetti?.emitterShape = node.geometry

    let confettiNode = SCNNode()
    confettiNode.addParticleSystem(confetti!)
    confettiNode.position = node.presentation.position
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(confettiNode)

    let fire = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Ar.scnassets/fire", inDirectory: nil)
    fire?.loops = false
    fire?.particleLifeSpan = 0.1
    fire?.emitterShape = node.geometry

    let fireNode = SCNNode()
    fireNode.addParticleSystem(fire!)
    fireNode.position = node.presentation.position
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(fireNode)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
        self.killedLabel.text = "Killed: \(self.killedCount)"
        self.dronesOut -= 1
    }

}
```

Any pointer to the right direction for solving this crash would be greatly appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1G93.png)

Comment: In your debugger output `ldrb` means "load register byte", combined with Bad Access tells me you are trying to load a resource (some sound file?) that isn't there. it seems this audio file is part of the node, and it exists or doesn't. Find the exact line causing the issue, you are most likely referencing a node that doesn't have this resource. Instead of making this part of the node consider checking which (kind of) node it is first and playing the appropriate sound for each, so you are referencing a resource independent of the node. Good luck!

Comment: Actually all the sound resources referenced play and load correctly, the crash seems to happen when there is a bit number of objects loaded ( each playing its own looping sound file). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are these sound resources non-optional? consider loading them as `Optionals` and use optional chaining to safely unwrap them, this doesn't fix the root cause of the issue but will prevent the app from crashing. At some point it seems ARC is releasing your `unowned` property that references the resource.

Comment: I have updated the section of the code that shows how they are loaded, basically unwrapping them in ViewDidLoad, then attaching them to objects as they are loaded from the function that spawns them with the timer as per above. Will try out your suggestion - thanks again! Just so I understand, the debugger indeed indicates that the crash seems to come from the Audio aspect of the program?